# Double quotients

Tags: math-mode

I would like to get something like double quotients i.e. something like this `G\X/H` where `X` is a group and `G,H` are subgroups of `X`. With

```
\sideset{_{G}}{^{X}}{\mathop\backslash}
```

I get `G\X` but I have no idea how to get `G\X/H`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What do you want have different from `$ G\backslash X/H $`?

Comment: Hi. It is hard for me to explain. I want the X to be higher up and G and H below. Similar to \sideset{_{G}}{^{X}}{\mathop\backslash} or \modfrac{X}{H}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to use `\sideset` (it requires a math operator as third argument):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    This is my solution:
    \[
    _{G}\backslash^{X}/_{H}
    \]
    This only to show the difference w.r.t. the solution suggested in the comment:
    \[
    G\backslash X/H 
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Club-Mate You're welcome! Sometimes we think that LaTeX is complicated and act consequently :) I've also edited my answer to show the difference w.r.t. the solution of the first comment to your question.